# Safe area layout guide not working for UITableViewController in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

Seems like UITableViewController does not have **safe area layout guide** to set table view top and bottom margin as collapses with bottom layout in **iPhone X**. All view controller are working fine with safe area layout guide in storyboard for top and bottom margin. Except UITableView controller.

For reference I am attaching screenshot of **iPhoneX**. There you can see string **"wheat"** is not fitting inside of bottom safe area.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I believe this happens since the view of the view controller (which always takes the entire screen size) is the `tableview`.

Either use a `UIViewController` and add a table view under its `view` (and add constraints to respect the bottom safe area)

or

Set the table view content insets with:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.safeAreaInsets.bottom, 0.0);
```

if you use the latter and target iOS versions under 11 make sure you verify it with:

```
     var safeAreaBottom: CGFloat = 0.0 
     if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
         safeAreaBottom = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.safeAreaInsets.bottom
     }

     tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, safeAreaBottom, 0.0);
```

I also noticed this property of `tableview` in iOS 11 (but no description:/): `insetsContentViewsToSafeArea`

I didn't try it yet but you can give it a try. Maybe this is what you need out of the box

Comment: I tried `insetsContentViewsToSafeArea`, but didn't seem to help. According to this [article](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/supporting-iphone-x/), it's `true' by default.

Comment: But setting the `tableView.contentInset` as per your example works a charm!

Comment: Are you sure this still works in iOS 12.2? I cannot get this to work. It also does not work when setting `insetsContentViewsToSafeArea` to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

This is my current fix to force top and bottom safe area in `UITableViewController`. First you have to embed it in `UINavigationController` (hide the navigation bar if not needed), then:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureFakeSafeArea()
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
    super.viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()

    topSafeAreaHeight?.constant = view.safeAreaInsets.top
    bottomSafeAreaHeight?.constant = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
}

private var topSafeAreaHeight: NSLayoutConstraint?
private var bottomSafeAreaHeight: NSLayoutConstraint?

private func configureFakeSafeArea() {
    guard let view = navigationController?.view else {
        return
    }

    let topSafeArea = UIView()
    topSafeArea.backgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor
    var topConstant: CGFloat = 0
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        topConstant = view.safeAreaInsets.top
    }
    topSafeAreaHeight = topSafeArea.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: topConstant)
    view.addSubview(topSafeArea, constraints: [
        topSafeArea.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        topSafeArea.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        topSafeArea.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        topSafeAreaHeight!
    ])

    let bottomSafeArea = UIView()
    bottomSafeArea.backgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor
    var bottomConstant: CGFloat = 0
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        bottomConstant = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    }
    bottomSafeAreaHeight = bottomSafeArea.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: bottomConstant)
    view.addSubview(bottomSafeArea, constraints: [
        bottomSafeArea.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        bottomSafeArea.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        bottomSafeArea.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        bottomSafeAreaHeight!
    ])
}
```

It's just sad that we have to write all this code, so if anyone knows about more simple way to achieve this, please show us.

P.S. I've used this small `UIView` extension here:

```
extension UIView {
    func addSubview(_ child: UIView, constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]) {
        addSubview(child)
        child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
}
```